# how to make a div to be fixed in the layout(container)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/uLa02c62/1/). How to make that green div to have fixed position in the container?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">hey hou</div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br></div>

            <div id="fixed">This div should aligned to the left like yellow div and fixed</div>

        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Please not all elements must stay at same positions as they are now and **green div should be fixed!**

**So it should looks like this:**
[image]

**and when the user scrolls the site:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please note** that this only works on specific dimensions. You will need (a lot) of media queries and/or JavaScript/jQuery to get it working on all window sizes.

You can use `translateX` to reposition your div.

This is the CSS for the *#fixed* div:

```
#fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    background: green;
    width: 100px;
    transform: translateX(-265px);
}
```

Here is the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLa02c62/3/)

Comment: Clean approach but the green box stills break out of the container at smaller dimensions though.

Comment: An element can't have `position:fixed` **and** be fixed to a container. `position:fixed` is always in relation to the viewport.

Comment: I want to delete my answer because it is not working on all resolutions but it is not possible because OP accepted the answer...

Comment: @paulie_d then that's the correct answer to my question, and I wanted to delete this whole thread but I can't

Comment: @dontHaveName I believe that you would have to unaccept the answer before it can be removed and (possibly) allow the *question* to be deleted.

Comment: yes, but I still wouldn't be able to delete it because this question has 2 answers

Comment: Then perhaps if you expand the explanation of what you're trying to achieve (and why the existing answers don't work) and add a javascript & Jquery tag you might get answers that fit your requirements. The effect **is** possible...just not with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your fixed div to `absolute and position accordingly like this:

```
#fixed {
    position: absolute;
    left: -300px;
    top: 100px;
    background: green;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle with above codes: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/uLa02c62/2/

Comment: But I want that div to be a fixed

Comment: @dontHaveName Then please update your question but I was about the post the same answer as Andrew.

Comment: @dontHaveName Your question is unclear. Putting words in bold is not making it any better...

Comment: downvoting the question won't help you. It's clearly written it should be fixed in the title and also in the body.

Comment: @dontHaveName Is it possible to make a little sketch of the desired outcome?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87690/discussion-between-thomasbormans-and-donthavename).

Comment: @dontHaveName The **green div is currently fixed** in your current fiddle and it stays fixed as you want on scroll. What exactly do you want then?

Comment: when you zoom out the website the green div would stay on the left but content would be in the middle